# Update SELECT multiple list using another SELECT multiple values with javascript (using erichynds multiselect widget)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two multiselect boxes (using [this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) plugin) to display a list of parameters in several different sections.

```
<select id="select_A" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="sec-1" id="main1">section1</option>
    <option value="sec-2" id="main2">section2</option>
    <option value="sec-3" id="main3">section3</option>
</select>

<select id="select_B" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="section-1" id="sub1">
        <option value="1A">1A</option>
        <option value="1B">1B</option>
    <optgroup label="section-2" id="sub2">
        <option value="2A">2A</option>
        <option value="2B">2B</option>
    <optgroup label="section-3" id="sub3">
        <option value="3A">3A</option>
        <option value="3B">3B</option>
</select>
```

From the sections list, I select a few, then pass the values with a form get and submit input to fill the parameters list.

I want to get rid of the “click to submit” step and populate the second list dynamically ie : if I choose section1 and section3, second list is filled with section1 and section3 and their respective sub options, if I add section2 , second list is refreshed and filled with section1,2,3 and their sub options.

Is there a way to do it using javascript ?

Not related with what I want to do but why aren't the functions working when applying the plugin (uncommenting these lines) on #select_B ? Is there a conflict ?
http://jsfiddle.net/8T6fU/10/

```
$(function(){
    $("#select_B").multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: "Choose Parameters"
    }).multiselectfilter();
});
```

**-----------------Edit-----------------**

This is what I tried :

jsfiddle.net/8T6fU/22/ (removed the http because I couldn't put two links in same post)

```
function TestSubCat()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("SubCat");
    var optG = document.createElement("OPTGROUP");
    var G = select.getElementsByTagName("optgroup");

    //var optGExists = G[0].length < 0;
    //if(typeof G[0].label != null){alert("undef");}
    //alert(G[0].label);
    var optGExists = select.length < 0;

    if(document.getElementById("Category").options[0].selected == true && !optGExists)
    {          
        if(optG.label !== "FirstCat")
        {
            optG.label = "FirstCat";
            select.appendChild(optG);
            optG.appendChild(new Option("reboot","FirstCat[reboot]"));
            optGExists = true;
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("Category").options[0].selected == false)
    {
        select.remove(0);
        optGExists = false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("Category").options[1].selected == true)
    {
        if(optG.label !== "SecondCat")
        {
            optG.label = "SecondCat";
            select.appendChild(optG);
            optG.appendChild(new Option("Port","SecondCat[Port]"));
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("Category").options[1].selected == false)
    {
        select.remove(1);
    }

    $("#SubCat").multiselect("refresh");
}
```

I know the optGExists is wrong, but can't get right..
Basically I want to avoid appending if the optgroup label already exists in SubCat list.

I also have a problem with the select.remove(). For testing purposes I just hardcoded the index. How can I remove the values related to the right optgroup ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do an on change event for the first select box:

```
$('#select_A').on('change', function(){
    $("#select_B").multiselect({
         noneSelectedText: "Choose Parameters"
    }).multiselectfilter();
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. When selecting an option from the first box, it just activates the multiselect plugin.

Comment: Found out I have to use $("#select_B").multiselect("refresh"); to actually show the changes. That answers my second question.